# zipPartitions : force both partitions to be persisted on the same executor

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's say I have 2 `RDD`s, each of them being partitioned and each of them persisted.

Now I'm calling `zipPartitions` in order to iterate over each pair of `RDD`'s partition.

Is there a way to ensure minimal data transfer? That is to say, can I ensure that `partition0` of `RDD1` was persisted at the same location as `partition0` of `RDD2` and so on?

Comment: It seems that it's somewhat covered here : https://blog.imaginea.com/investigations-into-spark-rdd-join/